# Cognos cross tab column with different measure

Tags: tabs, crosstab, measure

```
quantity                         total                          

measure   lv1  lv2  lv3    summary  lv1%  lv2%   lv3%                    

 xyz  |    2    1    4       7   
 frs  |    4    4    1       9                how to find the each level % ?
 sdfkj|    4    1    1       6
```

From my package data I used case statement to display those columns and quantity is the measure of my cross tab.

My question is: how can I find the % value of each level as we know the metric is like each cell divided by total summary. but how will that reflect in my table if the cross table measure is quantity. xyz, frs, sdfkj are rows displayed for my query row and lv1,lv2,lv3 are my columns and total summary is the summary option to find the total of 3 levels.i am using cognos 10.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

**lv1%**

```
[lvl1]/([lv1] + [lv2] + [lv3])
```

**lv2%**

```
[lvl2]/([lv1] + [lv2] + [lv3])
```

**lv3%**

```
[lvl3]/([lv1] + [lv2] + [lv3])
```